# Is there any software that tells precise location of a phone number?

Tags: gratis, android, maps, gps, phone

Is there any software that can track person's movement over a map, just by entering their phone number? (unknown to them)

His exact location must be shown on the map. Must be precise, fast, with live updates. Should work in the whole world, or in as many countries as possible.

It must be free of cost.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and tell us more. Do you want live updates? How fast,how precise? You are not even telling us for what OS....

Comment: I further assume this shall happen with the owners full consent, so whoever has the "tracked device" must actively opt-in to enable tracking. Otherwise it might be illegal for us to present answers. If this opt-in is OK, please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](http://meta.softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) – and then, as Jan already suggested, please [edit] your question accordingly.

Comment: It is not clear if you mean that you want to track one phone using a second phone, or just to track a single phone

Comment: yea using another phone in hand or using software on PC. And for OS part, Its windows on PC and Android on phone. @JanDoggen Mawg

Comment: Please answer *all* questions asked here (especially don't sidestep the one about legal consent) and [edit] your question so that all relevant information is in there. Add tags *gratis* *windows* *android*. Comments disappear.

Comment: Alright! It is illegal. I was asking this to track my girlfriend. We are done & lets close this topic. Thanks to all @JanDoggen

Comment: I don't think it is a bad question. It is just a question that gets a "there is no such software" answer. Legality/morality is not a valid close reason either.

Comment: Try [this app on android](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.life360.android.safetymapd). You have similar apps but of-course other person has to connect with you and you have to have this app also.

Answer (score 5):

No software can do this.

The geographical information associated to phone numbers is confidential. It is known only by the network operators, and by the spies who can see what happens at the network operators. They will not reveal it, especially not for free.

The network operator doesn't know the exact location anyway. The best they have is what cell the phone is connected to, which could cover a wide area.

Comment: okk sir! But I would still be researching about this and thank you. ;) @Nicolas Raoul

Comment: The network operator doesn't know the exact location anyway. The best they have is what cell the phone is connected to, which could cover a wide area.

Comment: Thanks @vclaw, I added your insightful info!